# SwiftUI Button tap only on text portion

Tags: swiftui

The background area of my button is not detecting user interaction. Only way to interact with said button is to tap on the Text/ Label area of the button. How to make entire Button tappable?

```
struct ScheduleEditorButtonSwiftUIView: View {

    @Binding  var buttonTagForAction : ScheduleButtonType
    @Binding  var buttonTitle        : String
    @Binding  var buttonBackgroundColor : Color


    let buttonCornerRadius = CGFloat(12)

    var body: some View {

        Button(buttonTitle) {
              buttonActionForTag(self.buttonTagForAction)
        }.frame(minWidth: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2) - 25, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)

                            .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.bold))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                            .border(Color("AppHighlightedColour"), width: 2)
                           .background(buttonBackgroundColor).opacity(0.8)

                            .tag(self.buttonTagForAction)
                            .padding([.leading,.trailing], 5)
       .cornerRadius(buttonCornerRadius)

    }
}
```

Comment: This is what you're looking for. I'd make an answer, but this explains in the best way possible: https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/09/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/

Comment: Excellent thank you that worked

Comment: Add some `padding`, and use `contentShape`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This fixes the issue on my end:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Button(action: {
            // Action
        }) {
            Text("Button Title")
                .frame(
                    minWidth: (geometry.size.width / 2) - 25,
                    maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44
                )
                .font(Font.subheadline.weight(.bold))
                .background(Color.yellow).opacity(0.8)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(12)

        }
        .lineLimit(2)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .padding([.leading,.trailing], 5)
    }
}
```

[image: button]

Is there a reason why you are using `UIScreen` instead of `GeometryReader`?

Comment: Did not know about GeometryReader. Thanks for the info I shall read up on it

Comment: Great answer. I had the size modifier on the button itself, and not the text :)

Answer (score 113):

The proper solution is to use the `.contentShape()` API.

```swift
Button(action: action) {
  HStack {
    Spacer()
    Text("My button")
    Spacer()
  }
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

You can change the provided shape to match the shape of your button; if your button is a `RoundedRectangle`, you can provide that instead.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, `.contentShape(Rectangle())` has been moved *inside* the button closure, otherwise it won't work on last versions of SwiftUI.

Comment: Yes, this is the real answer, which works whether or not you have a background color.

Comment: Adding .contentShape(Rectangle()) to HStack inside button worked for me

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, except I had to put it on the stack inside the button, not on the button itself.

Comment: If you use a custom ButtonStyle, then other solutions don't work. This is the true solution to the issue.

Comment: @EugeneStrelnikov's edit to move the contentShape to the hstack worked for me. perfect.

Comment: It looks like this does not work on watchOS

Answer (score 98):

I think this is a better solution, add the `.frame` values to the `Text()` and the button will cover the whole area

```
Button(action: {
    //code
}) {
    Text("Click Me")
    .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44, alignment: .center)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .background(Color.accentColor)
    .cornerRadius(7)
}
```

Comment: Great fix that makes sense.

Comment: this is not working on Xcode 11.5 beta. I tried two approaches, the one in the answer and also moving the size to a custom ButtonStyle

Answer (score 40):

You can define content Shape for hit testing by adding modifier: [`contentShape(_:eoFill:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:))

And important thing is you have to apply inside the content of Button.

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Select file")
       .frame(width: 300)
       .padding(100.0)
       .foregroundColor(Color.black)
       .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Add this line
}
.background(Color.green)
.cornerRadius(4)
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Another

```
Button(action: {}) {
    VStack {
       Text("Select file")
           .frame(width: 100)
       Text("Select file")
           .frame(width: 200)
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Add this inside Button.
}
.background(Color.green)
.cornerRadius(4)
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: this idea to use .contentShape(Rectangle())  fixed it for me

Answer (score 22):

## Short Answer

Make sure the `Text` (or button content) spans the length of the touch area, AND use `.contentShape(Rectangle())`.

```
Button(action:{}) {
  HStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Spacer()
  }
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

## Long Answer

There are two parts:

1. The content (ex. `Text`) of the `Button` needs to be stretched
2. The content needs to be considered for hit testing

To stretch the content (ex. `Text`):

```
// Solution 1 for stretching content
HStack {
  Text("Hello")
  Spacer()
}

// Solution 2 for stretching content
Text("Hello")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

// Alternatively, you could specify a specific frame for the button.
```

To consider content for hit testing use `.contentShape(Rectangle())`:

```
// Solution 1
Button(action:{}) {
  HStack {
    Text("Hello")
    Spacer()
  }
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
}

// Solution 2
Button(action:{}) {
  Text("Hello")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be doing this:

```
Button { /*to do something on button click*/} 
label: { Text("button text").foregroundColor(Color.white)}
.frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
.background(Color.black)
```

**Solution:**

```
Button(action: {/*to do something on button click*/ }) 
{ 
HStack { 
Spacer()
Text("Buttton Text")
Spacer() } }
.frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .center)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.background(Color.black).contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Answer (score 3):

I was working with buttons and texts that need user interaction when I faced this same issue. After looking and testing many answers (including some from this post) I ended up making it works in the following way:

For buttons:

```
/* WITH IMAGE */
Button {
    print("TAppeD")
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
}
/* WITH TEXT */
Button {
    print("TAppeD")
} label: {
    Text("My button")
       .frame(height: 80)
}
```

For Texts:

```
Text("PP")
    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture {
        print("TAppeD")
    }
```

In the case of the texts, I only need the `.contentShape(Rectangle())` modifier when the `Text` doesn't have a `.background` in order to make the entire Text frame responsive to tap gesture, while with buttons I use my Text or Image view with a frame and neither a .background nor a .contentShape is needed.

[Image of the following code in preview (I'm not allowed to include pictures yet )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br8fQ.png)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var tapped: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 19)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .foregroundColor(tapped ? .red : .green)
            Spacer()
            HStack (spacing: 0) {
                Text("PP")
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        tapped.toggle()
                    }
                
                Button {
                    print("TAppeD")
                    tapped.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                }
                .background(Color.red)
                
                Button {
                    print("TAppeD")
                    tapped.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("My button")
                        .frame(height: 80)
                }
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the answer, but I found two ways to do this —

### Option 1: Using Geometry Reader

```
Button(action: {
}) {
    GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Text("Button Title")
            .font(Font.custom("SFProDisplay-Semibold", size: 19))
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width - 20 * 2) // horizontal margin
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10) // vertical padding
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
}
```

### Option 2: Using HStack with Spacers

```
HStack {
    Spacer(minLength: 20) // horizontal margin
    Button(action: {

    }) {
        Text("Hello World")
            .font(Font.custom("SFProDisplay-Semibold", size: 19))
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10) // vertical padding
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(6)
    }
    Spacer(minLength: 20)
}.frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
```

My thought process here is that although option 1 is more succinct, I would choose option 2 since it's less coupled to its parent's size (through `GeometryReader`) and more in line of how I think SwiftUI is meant to use `HStack`, `VStack`, etc.

Comment: How dou sing the surrounding spacer effect that the whole button is sensitive to a tap event and not only it's text content?

Comment: For me second option it is better.

Answer (score 0):

this way makes the button area expand properly
but if the color is .clear, it dosen't  work‍♂️

```
                Button(action: {
                   doSomething()
                }, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Color(.white)
                        Text("some texts")
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used `HStack` then it worked for button whole width that's fine, But I was facing issue with whole button height tap not working at corners and I fixed it in below code:

```
Button(action:{
                print("Tapped Button")
            }) {
                VStack {
                   //Vertical whole area covered
                    Text("")
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                     //Horizontal whole area covered
                        Text("")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs to support both iOS/iPadOS and macOS, you may want to reference my code!

Xcode 14.1 / iOS 14.1 / macOS 13.0 / 12-09-2022

```
Button(action: {
    print("Saved to CoreData")
    
}) {
    Text("Submit")
    .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .center)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    #if !os(macOS)
    .background(Color.accentColor)
    #endif
}
#if os(macOS)
.background(Color.accentColor)
#endif
.cornerRadius(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier work around is to add `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` modifier.
and wrap your button inside a ContainerView. you can always change the size of the button where it's being used.

```
    Button(action: tapped) {
        HStack {
            if let icon = icon {
                icon
            }

            Text(title)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // This one
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are behaviours with SwiftUI which usually surprise developers:

- When you modify a button with `.frame`, it changes the container, but the button size didn't change. That's because the button label is fixed size.
- When you subsequently modify the frame with `.contentShape`, it doesn't change the button hittable area as you are modifying the frame

The initialization using `Button(title)` uses a fixed size label, which you can't do much about. The solution is to create the label view yourself.

```swift
Button {
  // action
} label: {
  Text(title)
    .frame(minWidth: 100, minHeight: 44)
}
```