# Swiftui button press does not always work

Tags: swiftui

When I press the button "Get New Connection Pin" it does not always print to console. Let's like I have to press the button a few times before it will print to console or for me to see the button visibly being pressed.

swiftui:

```
import SwiftUI

struct JokeView: View {
    @State private var jokeString = "No Joke Available"
    @State private var fetching = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Connection Pin:")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Button(action: {
                    print("Copy Connection Pin to clipboard")
                }) {
                    Text("3kus-32dak")
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Requesting a new connection pin")
            }) {
                Text("Get New Connection Pin")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(4)
            .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make the entire button tappable
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct JokeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        JokeView()
            .frame(width: 225, height: 225)
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code, seems that `.contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make the entire button tappable` is not actually accomplishing what you want it to accomplish and the text is still the only tappable portion of the button.

Fix is to apply your sizing transformations on the `Text` inside the `Button` `Label` instead of to the button.

For example (you could do it in a few ways):

```
Button(action: {
    print("Requesting a new connection pin")
}) {
    Text("Get New Connection Pin")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(4)
        .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Make the entire button tappable
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

More in here: [SwiftUI Button tap only on text portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333573/swiftui-button-tap-only-on-text-portion)

[This blog post](https://alejandromp.com/blog/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/) has a pretty good explanation too.

However, the following would be much simpler to accomplish more or less the same thing, plus you let the OS choose the sizes / colours somewhat (though it's only available in iOS 15+):

```
Button("Get New Connection Pin", action: {
    print("Requesting a new connection pin")
})
.tint(.blue)
.controlSize(.large)
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```