# SwiftUI Button with background image blocks interaction with adjacent buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a button with background texture. The texture is a large image and should be offset using geometry reader, so that it will match the texture position on the next screen.

Following code draws the button as expected

```swift
Button(action: action) {
            let imgSize = self.size - self.iconSpacing
            ZStack {
                GeometryReader { ctx in
                    let offX = ctx.frame(in: .global).minX * -1
                    let offY = ctx.frame(in: .global).minY * -1

                    Image(uiImage: self.txt)
                        .offset(x: offX, y: offY)
                }
                                
                Image(uiImage: self.img)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: imgSize, height: imgSize)
            }
        }
            .frame(width: self.size, height: self.size)
            .clipped()
            .accessibilityLabel(self.label)
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

Unfortunately, these buttons aren't usable. When using several buttons like this in an `HStack` only the last button responds to interaction. As if an invisible image overlaps the rest of them, moreover tapping on button right before the last one triggers the last button instead (assume that has to do with texture image size).

I've also tried using `.clipped()` on the rerader and image itself, placing the `GeometryReader` in the `.background()` etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333573/swiftui-button-tap-only-on-text-portion  using `.contentShape(Rectangle())`